# Scattering theory, which formalism?

Tags: soft-question, quantum-mechanics

I decided to have a sound study in quantum scaterring theory. I found two books which more or less fit my needs, but I have a couple of questions in which to choose for self-study.

[Taylor's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486450139) I saw that he treats the Møller operators very quickly in the course.

However, I got puzzled by the book of [Goldberger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486435075). In chapter five he says that there is the Møller formalism (and others), but that they will use the formalism developed by Gell-Mann Goldberger.

So my question is, which of the two approaches follow? I like more Goldberger book, but I want to know that his approach will be of use to me.

Essentially I work with the Landauer formalism and Non-Equilibrium Green's Function, but the sources tend to be scant inmaking the connection between Landauer and Scaterring theory.